# cannot get a variable to pass from function called onclick

Tags: javascript, function, variables, arguments

I am calling a function onclick `secVar(sec1);` which should run it through the script below, but it does not seem to be doing so, can someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly. I am new to javascript, and only have a little experience into scripting, and this code seems to be doing less and less of what I want it to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var sec1=0;
        var sec2=0;
        var sec3=0;
        function secVar(){
            if(sec1) {
                sec1++;
                document.getElementById('sec1text').innerHTML = sec1;
            }
            if(sec2) {
                sec2++;
                document.getElementById('sec2text').innerHTML = sec2;
            }
            if(sec3) {
                sec3++;
                document.getElementById('sec3text').innerHTML = sec3;
            }
        }

        function largestVar(){
                if (sec1 >= sec2 && sec1 >= sec3) {
                    //a
                    document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test1';
                } else if (sec2 >= sec1 && sec2 >= sec3) {
                    //b
                    document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test2';
                } else {
                    //c
                    document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test3';
                }
            }
    </script>
```

If this helps, The old code was the code below, before I tried to add in the script to determine the largest of the variables. It was incrementing the variables onclick, but no longer so. The onclick contained `sec1Var()` at that point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sec1=0;
    var sec2=0;
    var sec3=0;

    function sec1Var(){
    sec1++;
    document.getElementById('sec1text').innerHTML = sec1;
    }

    function sec2Var(){
    sec2++;
    document.getElementById('sec2text').innerHTML = sec2;
    }

    function sec3Var(){
    sec3++;
    document.getElementById('sec3text').innerHTML = sec3;
    }</script>
```

If someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's hard to tell what your intention is. Sparticus has it right *IF* what you're trying to do is see if sec1, 2, and 3 are currently true or false (0 or 1). Since they are currently false, the code will never do anything as Sparticus correctly points out.

However, I'm not convinced that's actually what you MEAN to do. It looks like the condition you want to check is whether or not you're trying to increment sec1, 2, or 3. In other words, "If you are passing me sec1, increment it and update a piece of HTML".

But variables don't work that way. When you say `secVar(sec1)` what you are actually saying is `secVar(0)'. I don't think that's your intention.

So, a big waste of my time if I'm wrong, but because I'm already rolling along, let's pretend I'm right:

secVar needs to be able to accept a parameter, but right now you've declared it void. Changing it to accept a parameter is a first step:

`function secVar(param) { ... };`

But this still won't do anything. Because when you're still passing it "0" with your existing syntax. You need to pass it something that can be checked, like a string:

`secVar('sec1');`

When you do this, you can now update your conditions to check which string is being passed

`if (param === 'sec1') { ... }`

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ch4yk/

**Notes:**

- The fiddle includes jQuery just for easy brute-force event binding on the buttons. It's just an example. You don't need jQuery; bind your events however you want.
- It is currently not doing anything with the largest value function, even though the code is in the fiddle

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, your jsfiddle, helped me a ton, sorry I was having a hard time explaining my problem. Thanks a ton,

http://www.sprayfoamsys.com/cmsdev/index.php?page=rig-constructor

Answer (score 0):

None of your counters will increment in this implementation.

When secVar() gets run, all the counters are at zero.  They never increment because they start at zero.